# Autoscale in mobile problems

Tags: css, class, responsive

in http://thebiztour.com/ a site with wordpress I'm having this issue:

normal text is re-scaling nice in mobile

but everything that it's under a  < div >  is not doing any resize and looks very small, it doesn't matter if you have the same font-size, or nothing related to that in the css related to this div

As you can see the text under the images is very small if you reduce the size of the screen

Now everything is working with sizes in vw and em, so, it should be more responsive.

Analyzing the css both texts have the same features, but they are working differently

Thanks!

Comment: Solved (more or less)
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
in header.php to avoid autoscale

Comment: Solved (more or less)
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
in header.php to avoid autoscale

and in style.css 
font-size: calc(30px + (20 - 30) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));

a little bit the opposite than expect, because the fonts need to be bigger in small screens

Answer (score 0):

If it's wordpress, then their themes are auto responsive. Anyways, use a site builder, like Elementor or WPBakery to create the website.